# grails saving object with hasmany relation through form

Tags: grails, grails-orm, grails-domain-class, grails-controller

I'm trying to create simple form for saving post with it's relations.
Here is my domain models;

Post Model;

```
class Post {

  String title
  String teaser
  String content

  static belongsTo = [author: Person, category: Category]
  static hasMany = [tags: Tag] 

  static constraints = {
  }

}
```

Tag Model;

```
class Tag {

  String name

  static belongsTo = Post
  static hasMany = [posts: Post]

  static constraints = {
  }
}
```

I've created a form for saving post object through html form;

```
<g:form controller="posts" action="save" method="post">
  <div class="input">
    <label for="post.title">Title:</label>
    <g:textField name="post.title" />
  </div>
  <div class="input">
    <label for="post.teaser">Teaser:</label>
    <g:textField name="post.teaser" />
  </div>
  <div class="input">
    <label for="post.content">Content:</label>
    <g:textArea name="post.content" />
  </div>
  <div class="input">
    <label for="post.content">Category:</label>
    <g:select optionKey="id" optionValue="name" name="post.category" from="${categories}" noSelection="['':'-Choose Category-']"/>
  </div>
  <div class="input">
    <label for="post.tags">Tags:</label>
    <g:select optionKey="id" optionValue="name" name="post.tags" from="${tags}" noSelection="['':'-Choose Tags-']" />
  </div>
  <div class="input">
    <g:submitButton name="Create" value="Create" />
  </div>
</g:form>
```

And here is the controller logic;

```
def save() {
  def post = new Post(params.post)
  post.author = springSecurityService.currentUser
  if(post.save()){
    flash.message = "Post created successfully..."
    redirect(action: "index", method: "GET")
  }
  else{
    flash.error = "Something went wrong, please check the form again!"
    [tags: Tag.list(), categories: Category.list()]
    render(view: "create")
  }
}
```

With this way i can't save tags for post object.

Comment: Out of morbid curiosity have you tried using post.tags.id as the element name?

Comment: yes I tried and did not work.

Comment: I found the problem, the problem is not about mapping, it's about saving tag_id and post_id into relation table. Have you got any idea about this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem with

```
post.save(flush: true)
```

here is the documentation about
[gorm save](http://grails.org/doc/2.2.x/ref/Domain%20Classes/save.html)